# Automatic augmentation of multiple packages

Tags: typescript, module-augmentation

I am currently implementing a CMS that is based on different packages. It has a package for `pages`, `core`, `files`, etc...

At the core of it all is a simple service registry, basically like this:

```js
interface Service {}
let registry: {[key: string]: Service} = {};


export function get (name: string) : Service|null
{
    return registry[name] || null;
}
```

Every package (`core`, `pages`, `files`, ...) registers a bunch of different core services. So now I though I might be possible, so that every package automatically augments the core service container declaration and adds explicit overrides:

So `core` can add:

```js
declare module "..."
{
    export namespace CMS
    {
        export interface Application
        {
            get(name: "confirm"): Confirm;
            get(name: "date.formatter"): DateFormatter;
            get(name: "fetch"): BackendFetch;
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

And `pages` can add:

```js
declare module "..."
{
    export namespace CMS
    {
        export interface Application
        {
            get(name: "slug"): SlugGenerator;
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

etc...

Right now that doesn't seem to work. I get it to work that **the own** services are recognized in the current package, but never the external ones.

My setup:

- in every package the types are in `src/@types/filename.d.ts`.
- TypeScript 3.6.4

What I would like:

- All the augmentations of all packages are automatically picked up

What I would like to avoid:

- That every package has to import all other packages that provides augmentations (because it should be as automatic as possible).

Comment: And if I need to explicitly import the other definition files (which didn't work in my test) – can I do that in my global and automatically imported `src/@types/module.d.ts`?